# Is it possible to locate and view the Skype cache in the newer versions?

Tags: skype

I've done some research, and apparently, since November, new versions of Skype don't make use of main.db. But I've found that it is possible to scroll up and view old messages without ever connecting to the internet, so they must be stored locally somewhere. Does anyone know where they might be cached?

This is on Ubuntu 16.04 and Skype 8.15.0.4.

Comment: Please include the Skype version in your question if you want an answer.

Comment: Which operating system do you use ?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04, Skype 8.15.0.4.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is a current version of Windows 10 and a current version of Skype DESKTOP.  If so, history should continue to work, add new messages, and show all past messages as well:

I've just tested the following:
**Skype DESKTOP**, (NOT the universal or web version):  `Version 7.40.0.151`
**Windows "Creator's Edition":**  `W-10 v-1709 Build 16299.248`

You should find the files here:
 `C:\Users\CURRENT-USER\AppData\Roaming\Skype\SKYPE-USER\`

My "Main.db" file is still there, and is currently about 35 MB.  I backed up this whole folder structure, (also adding it to "File History" AND running "RUN NOW" to manually back that folder up, by adding it AS a new library FIRST).

Then I ran my trusty (free) "SKYPERIOUS" database app, on that folder structure where I made a new copy of that folder.  ALL my messages from the beginning are still there and being added to in real time.  Normally you can just run Skyperious on that folder while live to VIEW or SEARCH messages.  Although do NOT attempt to repair or merge databases while Skype is open and live.  I did not try the Skype app itself to search, since I find it tedious, at best.

Comment: 7.40 isn’t the current desktop version, it also, isn’t distributed anymore

Comment: Yeah, this is exactly my problem. The most recent versions of Skype desktop, at least on my platform, don't store messages in main.db. They do, however, seem to be stored *somewhere* since it's possible to load them while not connected to the Internet.